# How to select a different autocomplete using the tab shortcut?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, directory

I type in for example: `cp /media/Macintosh`

I'm recovering someone's HD so I want to get 
Then <kbd>Tab</kbd> so that it can correctly put in the formatting for Macintosh HD

I then want it to complete among a few options if you press tab...

for this example there is Desktop and Desktop (old) how do I choose Desktop (old) when I type `De` <kbd>tab</kbd> <kbd>tab</kbd> it shows up there as a list of options but then I don't know how to choose the second option on the list.

I need the correct formatting for the directory "/Desktop (old)/"
and I can use tab to have it do that but I don't know how.

Now I have a new Problem:
I am doing a data recovery for someone:

```
-Ubuntu:~# cp /media/Macintosh\ HD/Users/orlando/Desktop\ \(original\)/VIDEOS\ ESPANOL/ /media/\$G\$\ DATA/Orlando/Desktop/
cp: omitting directory `/media/Macintosh HD/Users/orlando/Desktop (original)/VIDEOS ESPANOL/'
```

When I typed that this was my response:

```
-Ubuntu:~# cp /media/Macintosh\ HD/Users/orlando/Desktop\ \(original\)/VIDEOS\ ESPANOL/ /media/\$G\$\ DATA/Orlando/Desktop/
cp: omitting directory `/media/Macintosh HD/Users/orlando/Desktop (original)/VIDEOS ESPANOL/'
```

By the way I am logged in as root. What does this mean and how do I fix it?

---

Now that I know something and this question is popular:
Anybody know a way to modify your `bash_profile` so that you can use tab several times to cycle between different paths?

The correct answer for someone actually doing this would be to:
`cd ~/.bash_profile` or `~/.basher`

open the file with Sublime/TextEditorOfChoice/VIM/echo into the file:

Then copy and paste:

`bind '"\t":menu-complete'` OR: `bind TAB:menu-complete`

Then close and open your terminal/bash/commandprompt.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941055/how-do-i-make-bash-tab-complete-automatically-cycle-through-options-osx, http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24419/terminal-autocomplete-cycle-through-suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't "choose", you just keep typing. The <kbd>Tab</kbd> completion will stop as soon as it finds the 1st character that is different in the two files. So, using your example, you'd see

```
$ cd Desktop
Desktop/       Desktop (old)/ 
$ cd Desktop
```

You just need to keep typing. However, you have chosen to use strange names that contain spaces and parentheses. This is a bad idea since it makes them harder to deal with. To enter a space as part of the file name (it is normally taken to signify the end of a word or file name) you need to escape it with a backslash (`\`). So, in this case, you'd need to write `\` (that's <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>) and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again:

```
$ cd Desktop
Desktop/       Desktop (old)/ 
$ cd Desktop\ ##<--- hit Tab again here
```

It will magically complete to

```
$ cd Desktop\ \(old\)/
```

Note how the parentheses will be automatically escaped as well.

---

The above is how Ubuntu's default shell (`bash`) works. Other shells let you hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> again to cycle through the available options. For example, both `zsh` and `fish` let you cycle through and choose the one you want. Both are in the repositories so you might want to check them out.

Answer (score 2):

In windows if you type `Desk` and then <kbd>Tab</kbd> it will cycle through all possible (case insensitive) matches. Ubuntu doesn't work quite like this (by default). With ubuntu if you type `De` <kbd>Tab</kbd> it will fill up to `Desktop` and then you need to tell it how it differentiates.

In general putting special characters (like spaces) in a file name is not good practice. There are two ways of selecting a *file* named "Desktop Old" and they are

```
Desktop\ Old
```

or

```
"Desktop Old"
```

In the first option the `\` acts as an escape character meaning that the character that comes after this should be interpreted not as a part of a command, or a separation of arguments, but rather part of the same argument that preceeds it. The second option simply puts it in quotes.

So, in your case what you would do is:

`cp De` <kbd>tab</kbd> --> `cp Desktop`

Now here you would want to type `\` which should then, once you press tab again, allow you to autocomplete the `(old)`.

Additionally, it's worth noting that the final command after autocompletion will look like:

```
cp Desktop\ \(Old\)
```

As parentheses are also special characters, like spaces.